# Recursive method function that counts binary 1s of an integer

Tags: recursion, python-3.x, binary

I want to write a recursive method function that takes a nonnegative integer n as input and returns the number of 1s in the binary representation on n. I am instructed to use the fact that this is equal to the number of 1s in the representation of n//2 (integer division), plus 1 if n is odd.

```
    Usage:
    >>> ones(0)
    0
    >>> ones(1)
    1
    >>> ones(14)
    3
```

ok so this is the code I got so far, it still doesn't work though. it gives me 0 no matter what I input as n.

```
     def numOnes(n):
     # base case
       if n==0:
          print (0)
       elif n ==1:
          print (1)
     # recursive case
       else:
           return numOnes(n//2)+numOnes(n%2)
```

Thank you

Comment: You can just write `bin(n).count('1')`. Do you know it? There is no reasons to make it recursive. Anyway, you should try something yourself.

Comment: If you do integer division by 2, you 'shift' the binary representation of the number to the right by one, losing the right-most bit. For example binary 101 is 5; divide by 2 and binary 10 is 2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These elements you need to do it yourself:

```
if integer & 1 == 1: # & is the binary and. & 1 will give the lowest bit
    # there is a 1 in the end

integer = integer // 2 # loose one bit in the end
# or
integer = integer >> 1 # loose one bit in the end
```

Tell me if you need more input.

Your code works for me:

```
>>> def numOnes(n):
     # base case
       if n==0:
          return (0)
       elif n == 1:
          return (1)
     # recursive case
       else:
           return numOnes(n//2)+numOnes(n%2)


>>> numOnes(0b1100011)
4
```

Comment: I updated the code a little bit - still not seeing the problem

Answer (score 0):

You use `print` instead of `return` for the two base cases. Fix that and it'll work:

```
In [2]: numOnes(15842)
Out[2]: 9

In [3]: bin(15842).count('1')
Out[3]: 9
```